# Combine Cell Contents into another Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

So Im working on a Spreedsheet in Google Docs, my question is: I would like to combine say columns A,B,C,ect... in column I with a space between them. I'm currently using something like this =A1&" "&B1&" "&C1&" "&ect... This works fine and dandy but if the cell is blank I would like to ignore it. Should this be done via script or formula?

So in my head I'm thinking if cell A = value then grab it and combine it with B (if that contains a value if not leave blank or skip) But I'm not good at PHP So any help would be great!!! Happy NY to everyone ;  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a custom function that will return a string with the given range values joined by the given separator. Any blanks are skipped.

```
function joinVals( rangeValues, separator ) {
  function notBlank(element) {return element != '';}

  return rangeValues[0].filter(notBlank).join(separator);
}
```

Examples:

```
   A B C        Formula                Result
1  1 2 3   =joinVals(A1:C1," x ")      1 x 2 x 3
2  1 2     =joinVals(A1:C1," x ")      1 x 2
3  1   3   =joinVals(A1:C1," x ")      1 x 3
4  1 2 3   =joinVals(A1:C1)            1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [`IF`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093364) and [`ISBLANK`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093290) you can determine whether a cell should be included, or ignored. Like this:

```
=if(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1 & " ")
```

That reads "if the cell is blank, ignore it, otherwise echo it with a trailing space." You can daisy-chain a series of those together:

```
=if(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1 & " ")&if(ISBLANK(B1),"",B1 & " ")&if(ISBLANK(C1),"",C1 & " ")...
```

That gets pretty long and repetitive. Adding [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093275) and [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094077), we can have that repetitive piece apply across a range of cells, `A1:F1` in this case:

```
=JOIN("",ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:F1),"",A1:F1&" ")))
```

Comment: Ok now... Basucally what I have is 3 cells L x W x H I've got these all merged but now I want to display the "x" dependant on cell contents. This is where I am

Comment: =if(ISBLANK(E435),"",E435 & "''")&if(ISBLANK(F435),""," x ")&if(ISBLANK(F435),"",F435 & "''")&if(ISBLANK(G435),""," x ")&if(ISBLANK(G435),"",G435 & "''")

Comment: The issue I have is the x is very dependent some only have L some L x W some W x H or H only... So I dont want x H reading out just H. If you follow.

Comment: =CONCATENATE(A2 &"''"," ",B2 &"''"," ",C2 &"''") This works as well But I still need the x to separate L x W x H But I just cant get it work dependent on another cells value correctly.

Comment: Mogs, This works. The only issue is having two cells with formulas. I cam up with OR statement: anyway to shorten this? IF(E434="","",E434&"''")&IF(OR(E434="",F434=""),""," x ")&IF(F434="","",F434&"''")&IF(G434="",""," x ")&IF(G434="","",G434&"''")